# checked mongoose sava() data Create document if not exists, otherwise, update data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

i have mongoose schema save ever 1 sec if data is already exists update that document

```
   this.sub.on('message',async function (topic, message) {
        const soilesensor = new SensorModel({
            topic: topic,
            value : parseFloat(message.toString())
          })
          await soilesensor.save();
          cb && cb(topic,message); 
    })
```

my mongoose schema is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const sensor = mongoose.Schema({
    topic : {type : String ,index : true},
    value : {type :Number ,index : true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now ,  index: true}
})

const Sensor = mongoose.model('Sensors' , sensor )

module.exports = Sensor ;
```

i just save document if data is already exists update that document

Comment: you need to add the mongo _id to the model and the object being sent to save, only then mongoose will know what document to look for. Otherwise you have to rely on some unique field and find if the document exists and resave with new data.

Comment: can you provide me some example code how it possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). You need to pass `upsert: true`

Try below example:

```
db.books.update(
   { item: "ZZZ135" },   // Query parameter
   {                     // Replacement document
     item: "ZZZ135",
     stock: 5,
     tags: [ "database" ]
   },
   { upsert: true }      // Options
)
```

Comment: can i add this to mongoose schema